# I want to use VB.net to Format a Date Column in an Excel worksheet after exporting DataGrid from VB.net

Tags: excel, vb.net

Just a the piece of the code where I try to format the column - the export from datagrid works ' fine so not included here... the

```
Dim xlApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application

Try

Dim xlWorkbook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(FullFileName)

Dim xlWorksheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
xlWorksheet = CType(xlWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1"), Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)     
xlWorksheet.Activate()
```

this line (below) is the issue - it does not work as it is written - what am I missing?

I am looking to set column B as a Short Date format.

when I do it manually in Excel is works fine but I need to format it as part of the VB code rather than doing it manually in the Excel GUI.  when I open the worksheet Excel shows 44474  and then when you format it to short date it changes to `10-05-2021` which is what I would like it to be

```
xlWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B10").Numberformat = "*MM-dd-YYYY"


Catch ex As Exception
Throw Exception
Finally
xlApp.Quit

End Try
```

Comment: Did you try removing the `*` in the `NumberFormat` you're setting? I've never seen an asterisk in a date format before, in Excel or anywhere else.

Comment: How are you outputting the dates from the DataGrid into the corresponding cells in Excel?  Are you doing any type casting/formatting there?

Comment: Hi ! Thx for your replies:

Comment: Hi ! Thx for your replies: I have tried without the * and no diff. this line won't compile says "Sheets is not a member of Worksheets" so remove sheets and cut it back to  ws.Workbook.Worksheets.Range("B1:B10").NumberFormat = "*MM-dd-YYYY" it says Range is not a member of ExcelWorksheets...  I have not done any formatting as I export it.  See Below is the export is just two lines exporting from DataGrid Access.DBDT .   Dim ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1")
 ws.Cells("A1").LoadFromDataTable(Access.DBDT, True)